# How can I get the first character of the node title?

Tags: 8, theming

In the node--my-content-type.html.twig, I want to add the French indefinite article to the title, which depends on the first letter of the word to which the article is added.

- Banane => de Banane
- Orange => d'Orange

So based on the [Twig documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/), I'm trying to use one of the following code lines.

```
{% if label|first|lower == o %}
```

```
{% if label|slice(0, 1)|lower == o %}
```

```
{% if label[:1]|lower == o %}
```

None of them work.

How can I get the first character of the node title?

Comment: I would do this sort of thing in a preprocess function.

Comment: Looks like it could be done with twig's split https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/split.html but Kevin is right really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 * @param $variables array
 */
function TEMPLATE_preprocess_node(&$variables)
{
  /** @var \Drupal\node\Entity\Node $node */
  $node = $variables['node'];
  $title = $node->getTitle();
  if(_isFirstCharIsVowel($title)){
    $variables['title_addition'] = "D'";
  }else {
    $variables['title_addition'] = "De ";
  }
}

/**
 * Check if the first character is a vowel
 * @param $string string
 * @return bool
 */
function _isFirstCharIsVowel($string){
  $vowels =
    'aàáâãāăȧäảåǎȁąạḁẚầấẫẩằắẵẳǡǟǻậặæǽǣ' .
    'AÀÁÂÃĀĂȦÄẢÅǍȀȂĄẠḀẦẤẪẨẰẮẴẲǠǞǺẬẶÆǼǢ' .
    'EÈÉÊẼĒĔĖËẺĚȄȆẸȨĘḘḚỀẾỄỂḔḖỆḜ' .
    'eèéêẽēĕėëẻěȅȇẹȩęḙḛềếễểḕḗệḝ' .
    'IÌÍÎĨĪĬİÏỈǏỊĮȈȊḬḮ' .
    'iìíîĩīĭıïỉǐịįȉȋḭḯ' .
    'OÒÓÔÕŌŎȮÖỎŐǑȌȎƠǪỌØỒỐỖỔȰȪȬṌṐṒỜỚỠỞỢǬỘǾŒ' .
    'oòóôõōŏȯöỏőǒȍȏơǫọøồốỗổȱȫȭṍṏṑṓờớỡởợǭộǿœ' .
    'UÙÚÛŨŪŬÜỦŮŰǓȔȖƯỤṲŲṶṴṸṺǛǗǕǙỪỨỮỬỰ' .
    'uùúûũūŭüủůűǔȕȗưụṳųṷṵṹṻǖǜǘǖǚừứữửự'
  ;
  // set necessary encodings
  mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
  mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
  $first = mb_substr($string, 0, 1);
  $vow = mb_ereg_replace('[^'.$vowels.']','',  $first);
  return !empty($vow);
}
```

This can be used in your `.theme` or `.module` file.
This of course will act on all nodes, so you need to add your type checking.
The `_isFirstCharIsVowel` function can be in a service, I placed it here for simplicity

---

UPDATE
Credits for vowwl detectioon goes to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268970/how-to-detect-and-echo-the-last-vowel-in-a-word

Comment: WOW ! It works perfectly. Thank you SO MUCH. Following the advises of the previous comments, I was trying to figure out how to preprocess the regex function, and I was far from it...

Answer (score 1):

A preprocess function is better suited for this task, and I would use the following code. I am using *custom-type* as machine name for the content type; replace it with the one you are using, and for which you want to change the title.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($node = $variables['node'] && $node->bundle() == 'custom-type') {
    $title = $variables['label'];
    $translitted_title = iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", $title);
    $article = (in_array($translitted_title[0], ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']) ? "D'" : 'De ');
    $variables['label'] = $article . $title;
  }
}
```

In the template file, using `{{ label }}` you will get the changed title.

If you want to still be able to use `{{ label }}` for the original title, I would use the following code.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($node = $variables['node'] && $node->bundle() == 'custom-type') {
    $title = $variables['label'];
    $translitted_title = iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", $title);
    $article = (in_array($translitted_title[0], ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']) ? "D'" : 'De ');
    $variables['changed_label'] = $article . $title;
  }
}
```

In the template, you can now use `{{ changed_label }}` for the new title, and `{{ label }}` for the original title.

Replace *mymodule* with the machine name of the module, or theme, where the code is being added.

As said in [the documentation for the iconv extension](http://php.net/manual/en/iconv.installation.php), the extension is enabled by default. If the code I shown doesn't work, the extension has been disabled on the server.